# Web API validation of serialized string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am not sure how to validate a model in web API, when we receive it as a serialized string.

I use DataAnnotations on my model for validation purposes, and I usually do this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Save([FromBody] IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In this specific case, the "model" is coming from a serialized string:

```
public IHttpActionResult Save()
{
    string Data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Data"];
    IEnumerable<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<User>>(Data);

    // ...
}
```

How could I possibly validate this?

Comment: Can you use a custom model binder? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example above:

```
        // Validate
        Validate<List<User>>(user);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new InvalidModelStateResult(ModelState, true, new DefaultContentNegotiator(), Request, new MediaTypeFormatter[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }); // Force JSON
        }
```

Thank you.